# how to use XML in Sdk for web base application?

Tags: iphone, radix

I'm want to know how's correct way to use Xml in sdk for web base application
i'm trying to do magazine in iphone but they told me that i have to use XML to take body and other thing from that web site?
please some one direct me to that and if you have any tutorial for that
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I *think* I know what you're talking about, but it may be off because your English is a little off.

I think you're trying to parse the HTML of a web page. The easy way to do this (assuming the web page is valid XHTML), is to use NSXMLParser. It's an event driven parser, so you provide a delegate and as the parser moves through the document it will send messages to your delegate. Watch to see if the opening element is a body tag, grab the string, then close the string when the closing body tag is found.
The Apple guide is [here](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/XMLParsing/XMLParsing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000186i)